# how to make ( getitem Method ) in sectionspageradapter class return FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

The **getItem Method** does **return Fragment** but I want it also  to return **FragmentActivty** at the same time

So I have a **( tap Layout that have 3 taps )**

```
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
        switch (position)
        {
            case 0:
                return new Fragment();
            case 1:
                return new Fragment();
            case 2:
                return new FragmentActivity(); //error 
        }
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }
```

Comment: getItem has a return type of fragment and it can only return fragment.

Comment: What should I do because it is @override should I change all the classes to extend Fragment or FragmentActivity

Comment: classes to extend Fragment